# Difference between a Fingerboard and a Hangboard

Tags: gear, climbing, terminology

This is just a climbing terminology question:

**What is the difference between a Fingerboard and a Hangboard?**

Maybe there is no difference at all? Maybe it's subtle?  I have been Googling around and asking people and have gotten no consistent answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A fingerboard, hangboard, and training board all refer to the same thing: a device used to train for climbing that mounts on a wall or other vertical surface to improve strength and endurance.

> [What is a Fingerboard?](http://www.moonclimbing.com/blog/school/fingerboard/)
>
> A fingerboard is made from either wood or resin, and can be as small
> or as big as you like. Ideally it should fit above your door frame and
> have a variety of holds including a large hold to warm up on, a few
> pockets, slopers and a couple of different sized crimps...
>
> ...It is not essential to own a Moon fingerboard for this routine, but is
> recommended, since I will specify the exact holds to use on the Moon hangboard
> for each exercise...

"[The hangboard (aka fingerboard) is a popular training tool for
climbers, as it addresses the weakest link to the rock: the fingers.](http://www.nicros.com/training/articles/effective-hangboard-training-part-1/)"

[image: Metolius Simulator]

Comment: Thanks for the references. Particularly the second one, which seems to use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: Yeah man! I edited the first reference to include another sentence from that same page that also uses the terms interchangeably.